# For image upload, should I add a field to the MYSQL database to check against, or simply use PHP to check if the image exists?

Tags: php, mysql, image, file-upload

I have a simple image upload form.  When someone uploads an image, it is for a football pool, so there always is a `$poolid` that goes with the image they upload.

Right now, I am naming the uploaded image using the poolid.  So for example, if someone uploads an image, it might get named P0714TYER7EN.png.

All the app will ever do is, when it outputs the football pool's page, it will check to see if an image exists for that pool and if so, it will show it. It checks like this:

```
if (file_exists("uploads/".$poolid.".png")) { //code to show it }
```

My first thought when planning this was to add a field called "image" in my MYSQL database's table for all the pool information (called `pools`) and I would store a value of either the image name (P0714TYER7EN.png) or empty if there wasn't one uploaded.  Then I would check that field in the database to determine if an image exists or not.

But I realized I don't really need to store anything in the database because I can simply use the PHP `file_exists` check above to know if there is an image or not.

In other words, it would seem redundant to have a field in the database.

Everything works doing it this way (i.e. NOT having a field in the database) but I'm wondering if this is bad practice for any reason?

If anyone feels that I should absolutely still have a field in the database, please share your thoughts.  I just want to do it the proper way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach could depend a lot on what exactly you're trying to do.  Seems like the options you would have is:

**File System Only**

Benefits would be the speed of accessing static files of an image and use of it in your HTML directly which makes it a more simple solution.  Also if you're comfortable with using these functions it will be faster to finish.

Drawbacks would be that you're limited to using `file_exists` and similar.  Any code to manage files this way has to be very specific and static.  You also can not search or perform operations efficiently on this.  In general relying on the file system alone is not a best practice from my experience.

**Database Only**

Benefits, you can use Blob type as a column with meta data like owner, uploader, timestamp, etc. in the same row.  This makes checking for existing files faster as well as any searching or other operations fast and efficient.

Drawbacks, you can't serve files statically using a CDN or even a cookie-less subdomain or other strategies for page performance.  You also have to use PHP and MySQL to generate then serve any images via code rather than just referring to the image file directly.

**Hybrid**

Benefits, basically the same benefits as both above.  You can have your metadata in MySQL with a MD5 hash and location of the file available as well.  Your PHP then renders the page with a direct link to the file rather than processing the Blob to an image.  You could use this in conjunction with a CDN by prefixing or storing the CDN location as well.

Drawbacks, if you manually changed names of files on the server you'd have to rely on a function matching hashes to detect this, though this would also affect a File System Only that needs to detect a duplicate file potentially.

---

TLDR; the Hybrid approach is what you'll see most software use like WordPress or others and I believe would be considered a best practice while file system only is a bit of a hack.

Note: Database only could be a best approach in specific situations where you want database clustering and replication of images directly in your database rather than to a file system (especially if the file system is restricted access or unable to be modified for any reason, then you have full flexibility on the DB).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the blob datatypes from mysql. There you can save the image as binary data next to the data about the football pool.

So when you want to load an football pool you simple fire an sql statement and check if it returns a result, if so load the image from the database and display the data, otherwise throw an error.

If you have very frequent access you can simply put the images into a seperate table and load the image independent of the data about the football pool. Additional set some cache headers on the image and put it in a seperate file, this way you could simply save the primary key of the images in football table. Then you want to display the web page you simply load another document, pass it the primary key of the image, there the image will be loaded, or if the browser has it in cache, will load it from cache without querying the database.

This way you also have a better consistency of data and images.

Answer (score 1):

Your uploading an image to specific folder and that too with **poolid** which will be unique. It should work just fine.

**Problem :**

The code you have written works great. But the problem is, for the first time if the image loaded is **.png** and second time loaded file in **jpeg** or **jpg** then file exists wont check that and hence it may fail.

**Caution :**

If you have already taken a caution to check that the image uploaded must and should be **png** than the file_exists will work great.

**Alternate Solution :**

In case if your not checking for the image type to be **.png** then I highly advice you to take a boolean image column in your table by **is_image_uploaded** or something which can be set once you upload the file every time.

This makes sure that in case next time you wan to upload the image then you can directly go and check in your database table and see that if is_image_uploaded column is set or not. If not set then upload or else ignore or do whatever you want